# intellisense in visual studio 2015 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, intellisense

I have a question about intellisense in visual studio.

For example I have this:

```
var pickRandomWord = function (words) {
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length )];
};

console.log(pickRandomWord(randomWords));
```

Then when in the return function I don't see the length propertie of words. If I type in visual studio 2015 words.There appears a message:

> intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for
>   this expression javascript

But if I do this:

```
var pickRandomWord = function (words) {
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length )];
};

var randomWords = ["Planet", "Worm", "Flower", "Computer"];

console.log(pickRandomWord(randomWords));
```

Then the intellisense works fine. I see then the length property. Why is this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `pickRandomWord` function doesn't know what type it will receive it's not able to predict the 'length' property.

As for your second example, when you prepare the array `randomWords` and call your function with it, VS will be smart enough to see "Ok, I will receive an array based on the implementation below.".
Important: Intellisense will not always be accurate and show the right properties. You could try Typescript - Intellisense is extremely good with it (due to the types obviously).